# DHCP client for DHCP testing and debugging

Tags: networking, dhcp

I am looking for a tool that requests and accepts a DHCP lease but does not actually configure an interface on the host. `udhcpc` from busybox comes close when using the "client ID" option but it does actually configure the real interface and if possible, I'd rather not have that so as not to muck up connectivity.

`sudo udhcpc -v -i wlp3s0 -x 0x3d:0100BEEFC0FFEB`

One of the things I'm trying to do is to exhaust the IP address pool on a primary DHCP server and make sure the secondary DHCP server takes over.  Furthermore, I want to make sure that the mapping of MAC address to IP numbers is observed.

Bonus points if the test tool supports an option to send the probe to a specific DHCP server (`dhclient` apparently has the -s switch for that, but I can't seem to get it to accept a "client ID" on the command line even though there is the -i switch which I believe is for that purpose).

Comment: Since this is for "abnormal behavior", you're unlikely to find a tool. OTOH, writing a simple DHCP mal-client to generate your test traffic in `perl`, or `C` or ... shouldn't be difficult. Read the DHCP RFCs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can use this for doing the kind of load testing you want, but I found this tool useful for basic DHCP debugging: https://github.com/CyberShadow/dhcptest

It allows you to send  out discovery packets with all sorts of DHCP options, including spoofing your MAC to try IP reservations, etc.